# Using batch script to compare contents of 2 folders recursively, and copy the difference to a third folder

Tags: batch-file

I have 3 folders relevant to this script.

**Folder 1** - contains all existing images (PNG), sorted into subdirectories ONLY, totalling thousands of individual files. None exist in the root folder.

**Folder 2** - newly obtained images all in the root folder. I don't feel it's important to explain how they are obtained, as opposed to the fact that there will be a mix of duplicate files and new files.

**Folder 3** - empty folder.

---

Due to folder 1 having the most files, I need to run a check of all the files in folder 2 to everything in folder 1 *recursively*, (and not the other way around, for performance reasons) then copy/move whatever is new to folder 3 (this way I can manually sift through and sort them accordingly).

**Comparison can be done purely based on file name.**

I've looked around forums extensively and found only 1 script that works the best, but relies on both folders having no subdirectories.

My problem is that I can't seem to get it to compare files to folder 1 recursively. It ends up just copying everything in folder 2 to folder 3, because it's checking against the root folder of folder 1, which contains nothing but subdirectories.

**Code in question:**

```
@echo off
set "Folder1=Folder1"
set "Folder2=Folder2"
set "Folder3=Folder3"

for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b "%folder2%"') do (
    if not exist "%folder1%\%%F" copy "%folder2%\%%F" "%folder3%" && echo Copied "%%F"
    )
pause
Exit
```

**Behaviour of above code:**

Loops through every file in folder 2, and if a file with the same name doesn't exist within folder 1 (root folder only), it will copy it to folder 3.

---

I'd like it to check folder 1 contents recursively, not just the root folder.

I've tried tweaking it in many ways, such as changing the IN to NOT IN, or trying to find something to make the `"%folder1%\%%F"` have a recursive parameter such as `"%folder1%\..\%%F"` but nothing has worked with my limited knowledge.

Preferrably I'd like the whole process to be done with only 1 script.

Thanks in advance for your help. Please let me know if further clarification on anything is needed.

Comment: Your code seems to be trying to copy both files and directories, _(even though `copy` doesn't copy directories, only the files within them)_, and you're only checking for those in the root of `Folder1`, _(which you've already stated are "sorted into subdirectories")_, not within the subdirectory structure of it. BTW, can you not use [tag:robocopy], with `/E` or `/S` and one or more of its `/XC`, `/XN` and `/XO` options, *(and possibly its `/FFT` option)*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if [not] exist` works only if you give it the whole path (which you can't, because you don't know, were it might be). So this approach doesn't help you.

Instead you could do a `dir /s /b "%folder1%\%%F" || copy ....`, but that means, you have to do a recursive `dir` for each file in `folder2` - that's not what I would call performance.

Better generate a text file with the files in `folder1` and use that as reference. (`%%~nxA` lists only **n**ame and e**x**tension of the files):

```
@echo off
set "Folder1=Folder1"
set "Folder2=Folder2"
set "Folder3=Folder3"

>Folder1Files.txt (for /r "%folder1%" %%A in (*) do echo %%~nxA)

for %%F in ("%folder2%\*") do (
  findstr /x "%%~nxF" Folder1Files.txt >nul || copy "%%F" "%folder3%\" && echo Copied "%%F"
    )
pause
Exit /b
```

(judging by your workflow description, consider `move` instead of `copy`)

Comment: That's worked marvelously. Thank you for all those explanations as well!